# how to migrate old repository into new repository, and retain the log

Tags: git, migration, repository

I have a git repository (repo1) for deployment purposes. The repo contains the folders *1*, *2*, *3* which store different types of the source codes and each has a log of a branch by multi request number (example, req# 1 under branch 1, req# 2 under branch 2, and these will merge into master).

now, I want to restructure my repository. I will create a big repository (repo2) which should contain the previous folders *1*, *2*, *3* and some new folders *A*, *B*, *C*, this is because, I still need to refer to all logs that I have been deployed in repo1.

How to create the new repo2 and still be able to keep all logs in repo1 ?

Comment: If I understand your question, you're asking how to do a subtree merge. See [How to use the subtree merge strategy](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) and [Pro Git: Subtree Merging](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you clone repo1 to repo2, you will have the entire commit tree including branches and all the history. Then you can just add folders A,B,C.

In fact, you could just add folders A,B,C to repo1 if you like.

Hope that helps?